# Получить список элементов одного столбца фрейма фрейма

Tags: python, postgresql

Есть фрейм, вытащен из postgresql через pandas

| pas_id | status_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Как из столбца status_id сформировать список, который при этом будет соответствовать группировке по столбцу pas_id?

Должно получиться следующее:
для `pas_id(1) = (0,1,2)`
для `pas_id(2) = (7,1)`
для `pas_id(3) = (0,4,2,1)`

ИТОГО: `list = [(0,1,2),(7,1),(0,4,2,1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямо вот "в лоб" решается: группируем, аггрегируем в кортежи, переводим столбец в список:

```py
df.groupby('pas_id').agg(tuple)['status_id'].to_list()
# [('0', '1', '2'), ('7', '1'), ('0', '4', '2', '1')]
```